# Node.js matching the url pattern

Tags: node.js, express, url-pattern

I need an equivalent of following express.js code in simple node.js that I can use in middleware. I need to place some checks depending on the url and want to do it in a custom middleware.

```
app.get "/api/users/:username", (req,res) ->
  req.params.username
```

I have the following code so far,

```
app.use (req,res,next)->
  if url.parse(req.url,true).pathname is '/api/users/:username' #this wont be true as in the link there will be a actual username not ":username" 
    #my custom check that I want to apply
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A trick would be to use this:

```
app.all '/api/users/:username', (req, res, next) ->
  // your custom code here
  next();

// followed by any other routes with the same patterns
app.get '/api/users/:username', (req,res) ->
  ...
```

If you only want to match `GET` requests, use `app.get` instead of `app.all`.

Or, if you only want to use the middleware on certain specific routes, you can use this (in JS this time):

```
var mySpecialMiddleware = function(req, res, next) {
  // your check
  next();
};

app.get('/api/users/:username', mySpecialMiddleware, function(req, res) {
  ...
});
```

**EDIT** another solution:

```
var mySpecialRoute = new express.Route('', '/api/users/:username');

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  if (mySpecialRoute.match(req.path)) {
    // request matches your special route pattern
  }
  next();
});
```

But I don't see how this beats using `app.all()` as 'middleware'.

Comment: I don't have app object inside the middleware. Also I just want to match the URL pattern.

Answer (score 3):

You can use node-js **[url-pattern](https://www.npmjs.com/package/url-pattern)** module.

Make pattern:

```
var pattern = new UrlPattern('/stack/post(/:postId)');
```

Match pattern against url path:

```
pattern.match('/stack/post/22'); //{postId:'22'}
pattern.match('/stack/post/abc'); //{postId:'abc'}
pattern.match('/stack/post'); //{}
pattern.match('/stack/stack'); //null
```

For more information, see: https://www.npmjs.com/package/url-pattern

Comment: I want to find a pattern from URI as I've multiple pattern store in DB, I want to authorise each URL in a microservice gateway.

Answer (score 2):

Just use the request and response objects as you would in a route handler for middleware, except call `next()` if you actually want the request to continue in the middleware stack.

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  if (req.path === '/path') {
    // pass the request to routes
    return next();
  }

  // you can redirect the request
  res.redirect('/other/page');

  // or change the route handler
  req.url = '/new/path';
  req.originalUrl // this stays the same even if URL is changed
});
```

Comment: I need to match this pattern "/api/users/:username" and I can't do that with simple comparison.

Comment: You can use `.split()` on `req.path` and check if `url[1] === 'api'`, `url[2] === 'users'`, etc.

Comment: Yes I can do that. I'm just wondering if there is some standard way of  doing that. Any node library etc. Thanks for the help so far.

Comment: There isn't really a standard way to match URLs, most would either used a regular expression or switch, is there is a reason why you want to put this routing into middleware rather than routes?